# Map IDictionary<string, string> with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm attempting to map an `IDictionary<string, string>` with Fluent NHibernate and have hit a road block.

I have 3 models,

```
public class Node {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<string string> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
}

public class NodeData {
    public virtual Node Node { get; set; }
    public virtual Field Field { get; set; }
    public virtual string Data { get; set; }
}
```

And my mapping looks like this

```
public NodeMap() {
    HasMany<NodeData>(x => x.Fields)
        .AsMap(x => x.Field.Name)
        .Element("Data");
}
```

However, this obviously will give an error because `Field` is a reference and not a property.

I'd like to be able to access my dictionary like, `Fields["name"] = value;`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you have a dictionary with `<string, string>`, where did this `Field` class come from? How would Fluent Nhibernate know about that?

Comment: @OskarBerggren The `NodeData` class has a composite key of `Node_Id` and `Field_Id`. The dictionary is essentially <NodeData.Field.Name, NodeData.Data>

Comment: "essentially" => not really. The dictionary is a <string,string> according to your code - it doesn't help to pretend otherwise in the mappings. There also seems to be some "circularity" here that I can't quite put my finger on.

Comment: So the NodeData has a Node which has a dictionary which is (should be) indexed by the Field in the NodeData. But NodeData has only one field, so why the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

just kick class `Field` and class `NodeData` and

```
public NodeMap()
{
    HasMany(x => x.Fields)
        .Table("NodeData")
        .KeyColumn("node_id")
        .AsMap("key")
        .Element("data");
}
```